# How do I remove the nCryptedCloud tile from Devices and Drives?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10

I'd like to remove the tile "nCryptedCloud" shown below, without uninstalling the program. It's not a folder that I can just delete in the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows` folder, nor could I find it in the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace

How can I remove it?

[image: Tile to remove from Windows My Computer]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the key, but if you don't plan on using it anymore you can safely do a scan in regedit for nCryptedCloud

In a fast search i found these keys that u can safely remove, BUT considering that this app acts in behavior of 4 other apps too, it would be wiser to use normal uninstall, if that didn't work u can try to reinstall the app and uninstall it again from control panel since, it seems it has many keys related to it, and removing manually may leave many keys behind that could end up in bad behavior in onedrive, google drive, ...

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{0ECE4426-2D77-4760-B532-2A51CD19C8CF}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{0ECE4427-2D77-4760-B532-2A51CD19C8CF}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{10F86B02-9D8D-4356-89ED-06B59ED992CF}

The installation path oddly is located in %appdata%\nCryptedCloud\ translates to
C:\Users\"YourUsername"\AppData\Roaming\nCryptedCloud\